# Can't give tags rels

Tags: posts, visual-editor, html-editor

In my Wordpress post I click on edit post and skip over to the html editor tab and click on it. I have a pre on that page and when i give it a rel and publish its all fine but when I skip back over to visual editor it just takes out the rel attribute.

Comment: Why do you want to add an invalid attribute to `pre`? `rel` is for links.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function extend_tinymce( $values ) {
    $elements = 'pre[id|class|title|rel]';
    if ( isset( $values['extended_valid_elements'] ) ) {
        $values['extended_valid_elements'] .= ',' . $elements;
    } else {
        $values['extended_valid_elements'] = $elements;
    }
    return $values;
}
add_filter('tiny_mce_before_init', 'extend_tinymce');
```

The above snippet is what I use for example, of course you can extend this beyond id, class, title, rel, to things such as height, width, style, name, etc...